# Xero API - Do Tax Rates have a Primary Key?

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to pull Tax Rate records from our Xero platform to our external app (so that user can apply the tax rates to invoice line items in the external app).

In order to keep those records up to date, I would usually rely on a Xero ID or other unique identifier. However with Tax Rates it seems they only identifier is the name (which obviously causes issues when a user updates a tax rate's name, or in the case of rates with matching names).

Am I missing a distinct primary key I can use?

Answer (score 1):

It seems someone has asked a similar question on the Xero community pages => https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/2622303

Comment: I found this also, but from what I can see TaxType is not distinct. Multiple TaxRates can share a TaxType, so this is not a reliable identifier.

Comment: @Talon In the above link, it is mentioned as  `Tax Type is used by Xero API to interact with Tax Rates so yes, it is unique in a Xero organization.`